# change pointer to *os.File

Tags: go

I have rotated files, and I need change files periodically, but I can't renew my pointer to file

```
var (
  file          *os.File
)

func init() {
    file, err = os.Create(fileName)
}

func main() {
  ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second * 6)
  defer ticker.Stop()

  go func(file *os.File) {
      <- ticker.C
      fn := fmt.Sprintf("%d%s", time.Now().Unix(), ".txt")
      file, _ = os.Create(fn)
  }(file)

  http.HandleFunc("/go", goHandler)
}

func goHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Printf("hand File: %v\n", *file)
  // when handler triggered file stay the same
  file.WriteString(myPayload)
}
```

it changes inside goroutines, but it doesn't react in handler, so the file stays the same all time.

Suggest, pls, how I can change pointer to `*os.File`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the goroutine only runs once. So it creates a single new file and does nothing more - which means `*file` only changed once.

You should change `<- ticker.C` to `for _ = range ticker.C { ... }`.

And also, you should guard changing and reading values from `*file` with a `sync.Mutex`, because there is a data race between two goroutine.

Comment: Sure you can, the channel value type doesn't matter.

Comment: @Himanshu In Go, you can range over channels. See: https://play.golang.org/p/NFAcZlCmMU2

Comment: @Himanshu however it is my mistake. It should be `_ = range` instead of ` _ := range`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use infinite `for` loop and `select` statement within this `for` loop (in case in the future you'd like to handle also other signals on other channels, e.g. graceful exit). Also, you need to handle assignment to a pointer correctly (you need to assign new value to the underlying value of a pointer). You could also drop passing the pointer to the goroutine, and just modify a global pointer outside of goroutine, but I am not sure if that's a good practice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var (
    file    *os.File
    fnMutex sync.Mutex
    err     error
)

const fileName = "testFile"

func init() {
    file, err = os.Create(fileName)
}

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 6)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    go func(file *os.File) {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                fn := fmt.Sprintf("%d%s", time.Now().Unix(), ".txt")
                fnMutex.Lock()
                newFile, _ := os.Create(fn)
                *file = *newFile
                fnMutex.Unlock()
            }
        }
    }(file)

    http.HandleFunc("/go", goHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func goHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fnMutex.Lock()
    defer fnMutex.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("hand File: %v\n", *file)
    // when handler triggered file stay the same
    file.WriteString("test:" + time.Now().String() + "\n")
}
```